# Recompiling Android RunTime

Tags: java, google-chrome, android

According to following image, ART is very similar to JVM.

[image: Android Structure]

As JVM is for Linux which converts Java instruction set to machine level instruction set. Then is there any way to recompile ART for linux environment which will help linux to create a layer to run android applications?

I found Arc Welder application for google chrome, It helps to run android apps in Linux. I done some RnD, I found there is a python script which helps to run android applications on linux. Similar way can we use this script mechanism to run android apps without any simulator like blue stack??

Simply an environment like wine which provides android apps executable platform.

Here is Arc Welder link.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn

Comment: How come ART similar to the official JVM? I guess Dalvik is *more* similar to JVM, ART compiles the app into **Machine Code** once the app is installed, while Dalvik and JVM **Interpret** the **Java ByteCode.** After Android 2.2, Dalvik uses JIT as JVM does

Comment: Have you seen this : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Specs/AndroidExecutionEnvironment and http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2009/05/canonical-developers-aim-to-make-android-apps-run-on-ubuntu/. Then update it to the Nougat or Marshmallow runtime

Answer (score 3):

#### Simple answer:

That's unlikely going to happen in the near future. (~10 years)

#### More elaborate  answer:

You're asking for "Simply an environment like Wine" or to quote [A.H. Weiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._H._Weiler): "Nothing is impossible for the man who doesn't have to do it himself …"

**What you're asking for is not impossible** *but* a nicely coloured square with lots of even more nicely coloured squares like [the Android Runtime Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLKD6.png) *running on ChromeOS* looking similar to another nicely coloured square like [the Java Architecture](http://www.cognitionis.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/JAVA.gif) *running on all OSes* doesn't mean that they are even remotely similar or that developing an API emulator is something that's going to happen …

It's so much easier cross-compiling your application on any *nix system and then actually running it **on** your Android phone / Chromebook in developer mode then going through the daunting task of developing CAINE (ChromeOS/Android Is Not an Emulator).

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news …*

Comment: Can't an emulator be considered such an environment?

Comment: @prakharsingh95: That depends of your definition of "emulator". **W**ine **i**s **n**ot an **E**mulator...