# How to install Android Runtime On Linux

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, ubuntu-for-android

How can i Install ART (Android RunTime) On Linux(Ubuntu)

And if i installed it can i run android apps natively on ubuntu

Without using an emulator

i hope you help me

thanks

Comment: Did you see this? https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/run-android-apps-games-linux/

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/644988/ . Same answer applies.